# nginx keepalive behavior with upstream

Tags: networking, nginx, tomcat

nginx can use keep alive connections with upstream. My question is that can the connections be reused by multiple different clients? To be more specific:

clientA --> nginx --CONNECTION--> tomcat

clientA make multiple requests using one keepalive connection with nginx and nginx makes a keepalive connection(CONNECTION ) with tomcat to transfer the data. After clientA finishes requests, there cames another clientB. When clientB make requests, can the previous connection(CONNECTION) between nginx and tomcat be reused for this request? And is there some docs pointing out this? Thanks